# Java - Unable to access a HashMap within a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, nested

I have checked over stack overflow but cannot find a solution to my problem!

I have a class which iterates over chars and turns a data text file into a hashmap, and am having the following problem.

Before I add the HashMap of data-key: value pairs to the HashMap of HashMaps it works fine, and I am able to access **this** data:

In ConfigHandler.java:

Temporary Map:

```
Map<String, String> tempHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Code (In a readable format):

```
this.containers.put(this.currentHashMapKey, tempHashMap);
this.currentHashMapKey = "";
//CHECK KEY, VALUE PAIRS
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry: tempHashMap.entrySet())
{
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();

    System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
}
tempHashMap.clear()
```

However once it has been added to the 'Super-HashMap,' though I am able to access the object with its key, the HashMap I get is blank.

(note this also doesn't work when directly within the ConfigHandler class)

In ConfigHandler.java:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getContainerList()
{
    return this.containers;
}

public Map<String, String> getContainer(String name)
{
    return (Map<String, String>)this.containers.get(name);
}
```

In the static{} method of another class (And In a whole bunch of try/catch):

```
staticReader.read(readerChars);
oreChanceConfig = new ConfigHandler(readerChars, false);

Map<String, String> chances = oreChanceConfig.getContainer("Chances");

if (oreChanceConfig.getContainerList().containsKey("Chances"))
{
    if (chances.containsKey("Saltpeter")) //It should contain this key, but doesn't
    {
        System.out.println("It actually Works"); //Does not get printed
    } else {
        System.out.println("Key Value Pairs:"); //this gets printed
        //the following loop prints nothing
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : chances.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
        }
    }
}
```

HashMap of HashMaps init code:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, String>> containers = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

Comment: Everything would be soooo much easier if, instead of using maps in maps, you defined classes, with names and typed properties and methods. What is clearer? List<User> or Map<String, Map<String, String>>?

Comment: Could your maps be “blank” because you’re executing `tempHashMap.clear();` after adding the map to the super map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I really understand your description of what you are doing, but this stands out:

```
    this.containers.put(this.currentHashMapKey, tempHashMap);
    // ...
    tempHashMap.clear();
```

When you call `clear()`, you remove all entries from `tempHashMap`.  Since this is the map object that you added as a value in the `containers` map, you are clearing it there *as well*.

One possible solution is to create a new `tempHashMap` on every iteration ... and don't call `clear()` after adding it to `containers`.

---

Explanation:

> I thought it created a copy of the HashMap when you added it.

You appear to think that

```
    this.containers.put(this.currentHashMapKey, tempHashMap);
```

will create a copy of `tempHashMap`.

This is NOT so.

In fact, what you are doing is storing the *reference* to your "temporary hash map" as the entry value in the `container` map.   Indeed, if you then reuse the temporary map, you will end up will many references to that one map object in your `containers` map.

A `Map::put(key, value)` operation does not copy / clone / whatever the `key` object or the `value` object.  It just stores the references in the map entry.  If you then mutate those objects:

- mutating the `value` changes what is visible via the map
- mutating the `key` breaks the mapping (!).

> Will it not overwrite the previous HashMap whenever I create a new one though?

No it won't.   It creates a **new** one.   Consider this:

```
    Map<String, String> tempHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    tempHashMap.put("key", "value");
    tempHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

The third statement creates a new `HashMap` object and assigns the reference to the `tempHashMap` variable.  That replaces the original reference value in the variable, but it does not affect the first `HashMap` object.  If you still had a reference to the original object, you could still lookup "key" and get the corresponding "value".

This is basic Java assihnment semantics.  Assignment of objects (either by using `=`, or by passing a parameter) ONLY assigns references.  It does NOT overwrite the actual object state.

This is different to C and C++ where assignment of objects (or structs) and assignment of pointers to objects / structs are fundamentally different operations.

Comment: Will try, Thanks :)

Comment: Did you **understand** why what you are currently doing is wrong?

Comment: Not Really... I thought it created a copy of the HashMap when you added it.     Will it not overwrite the previous HashMap whenever I create a new one though?

Comment: HEEEEY It works xD. I initially create the new HashMap<String, String>, then every time I need a new one I just do tempHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
Map<String, String> chances = oreChanceConfig.getContainer("Chances");
if (oreChanceConfig.getContainerList().containsKey("Chances")) {
......
}
```

By this:

```
Map<String, String> chances = oreChanceConfig.getContainerList().get("Chances");
if (chances != null) {
......
}
```

Hope this helps!